# Error in FAuthData integrating FireBase SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, firebase-authentication

I m facing issue while integrating facebook in firebase sdk in iOS app. However when I tried checking auth data using the given code in documentation. It returns nil data.

`Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:kFireBaseUrl];
    [ref observeAuthEventWithBlock:^(FAuthData *authData) {
        if (authData) {
            // user authenticated
            NSLog(@"%@", authData);
        } else {
            // No user is signed in
        }
    }];`